# MVC Razor TextBoxFor() based on other Model List of Complex Object

Tags: c#, html, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So I have a Model named Parties, that contains a List of Instructors.

I want to create TextBoxFor's based on the properties of the Instructor object.

When I do @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Model.Instructors...) I cant get the properties of the Instructor object without using a Select with Linq. If I use linq, I need to dynamically get the specific instructor I want. The information I need to get this instructor is based on a textbox somewhere else on the form, but how could I dynamically get the value of another textbox to satisfy the linq expression?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are trying to achieve.  It sounds (vaguely) like what you want is more of a MVVM architecture there, in which case you should be looking at angular or similar.  Maybe I misunderstood what you want.

TextboxFor can't generate a textbox for a List of objects.  What would you expect it to generate? A list of textboxes?  If all you want is a text box that has some unique name, then just pick an instance of one, like `@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Model.Instructors.FirstOrDefault().something)`

If by "dynamically get the specific instructor I want" means that they will pick it on the client side and you can edit a current existing record, then you probably should be sending down the list of instructors into a javascript array and then writing some client side code to pick it for you.  Alternatively, you can make an AJAX call if the list of instructors would be too large.  Why would you base it on a Textbox value, shouldn't it be based on a dropdown/select value?